# Can't validate Telegram Web App for Bots user

Tags: php, telegram

I've tried to do user verification script for telegram web app for bots. I have no idea how to fix it. The hash and encoded string are similar but not the same.

Telegram article (documentation): https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#validating-data-received-via-the-web-app

```
$bot_token="5368097647:AAFU8jBho71pglrzDeGw6LawrVuMmxaxpEQ";
$data_check_string=$_POST['a'];
$data_check_string=explode("&", urldecode($data_check_string));

foreach ($data_check_string as &$arrvalue) {
    $hash="";
    if (substr($arrvalue, 0, 4)=='hash'){
        $hash=explode("=", $arrvalue)[1];
        break;
    }
}

sort($data_check_string);

$data_check_string=implode('\\n', $data_check_string);
$secret_key = $sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $bot_token, "WebAppData");

if (hash_hmac('sha256', $data_check_string, $secret_key) == $hash) {
    print("fromtg");
}
else{
    print("notg");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Join the array with `implode("\n", $data_check_arr);`
- in the `hash_mac` functions set the fourth param to `TRUE` (outputs raw binary data);
- before compare the two hash apply `bin2hex` function to calculated hash to convert binary data into hexadecimal representation;

#### Here my code:

```
<?php

$data_check_arr = explode('&', rawurldecode($data_check_string));
$needle = 'hash=';
$check_hash = FALSE;
foreach( $data_check_arr AS &$val ){
    if( substr( $val, 0, strlen($needle) ) === $needle ){
        $check_hash = substr_replace( $val, '', 0, strlen($needle) );
        $val = NULL;
    }
}

// if( $check_hash === FALSE ) return FALSE;
$data_check_arr = array_filter($data_check_arr);
sort($data_check_arr);

$data_check_string = implode("\n", $data_check_arr);
$secret_key = hash_hmac( 'sha256', $bot_token, "WebAppData", TRUE );
$hash = bin2hex( hash_hmac( 'sha256', $data_check_string, $secret_key, TRUE ) );

if( strcmp($hash, $check_hash) === 0 ){
    // validation success
}else{
    // validation failed
}
```

Comment: Excellent work, but mine had some leading or trailing whitespaces that made the final strcmp fail. I simply used trim() thusly: strcmp(trim($hash), trim($check_hash)) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bot_secret = '0000:AABBK4';

$in = 'query_id=AAG1RDYIAAAAALVENghFqilw&user=%7B%22id%22%3A137774261%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22Max%22%2C%22last_name%22%3&auth_date=1684504221&hash=994359f95a92d541a1ff9f079342ed727dedb43175d80119d6d93eff156862cf';

parse_str($in, $arr);
var_dump($arr['hash']);

unset($arr['hash']);
ksort($arr);

foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    $data_str .= $k."=".$v."\x0A";
}
$data_str = trim($data_str);

$secret = hash_hmac('sha256', $bot_secret, 'WebAppData', true);
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $data_str, $secret);

var_dump($hash);
```